# Azure Function - Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to copy the value from the Excel file but it returns this error message:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.extract Result: Failure
Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: './data_download/xxxxx.xlsx'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 343, in handle_invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 480, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/extract/_init_.py", line 62, in main
    with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
```

My code

```
with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not related to Azure function, in general Only **`/tmp`** seems to be writable

Try adding tmp to the file path

```
filepath = '/tmp/' + key
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Azure Function resource uses a linux based operating system. All files are saved in the /tmp folder.

```
import tempfile
import os
   
local_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
filepath = os.path.join(local_path, filename)
```

And then you should be able to save any data to the filepath variable

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is struggling with this, I was going around and around trying to find an answer to this issue and the only thing that worked for me was found here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15211

[image]

[image]

Voila...

All is good.